# AS3 No keyboard input registering

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

so I want an object to orbit around another, but I want it to do it only when the right arrow key is pressed. When I run this program, the orbiter doesn't move at all, even when the right arrow key is pressed and it doesn't trace!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

PS Do I have to use an event listener with KEY_DOWN or can I return a number and check it?

```
var orbiter:Orbiter = new Orbiter();
var origin:Origin = new Origin();
var angle:Number = 0;
var speed:Number = 1.5;
var radius:Number = 75;
origin.x= 100;
origin.y =100;
addChild(orbiter);
addChild(origin);

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Orbit_Brah);
function Orbit_Brah(event:Event):void
{
    var nLeftOrRight = CheckKeyDown;
    if (nLeftOrRight == 1)
    {
    angle += speed;
    var rad:Number = angle * (Math.PI / 180);
    orbiter.x = origin.x + radius * Math.cos(rad);
    orbiter.y = origin.y + radius * Math.sin(rad);
    orbiter.rotation = (Math.atan2(orbiter.y-origin.y, orbiter.x-origin.x) * 180 / Math.PI);
    }
}

function CheckKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):int
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
        trace ("Key Press Registered");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a listener to fetch the info from the KeyboardEvents. Store the info in a variable and use it in your update loop. You may also want to use KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP to check when the keys are released as well. Something like this.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Update);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, OnKeyboardDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, OnKeyboardUpHandler);

function Update(pEvent : Event) : void
{
    // update code here using stored info
    if(_isMovingRight)
    {
        //
    }
}

function OnKeyboardDownHandler(pEvent : KeyboardEvent) : void
{
    switch(pEvent.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
            _isMovingRight = true;
            break;
    }
}

function OnKeyboardUpHandler(pEvent : KeyboardEvent) : void
{
    switch(pEvent.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
            _isMovingRight = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying too hard. All you need to do after your declarations is:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, Orbit_Brah);


function Orbit_Brah(e)
{
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) 
    {
    angle += speed;
    var rad:Number = angle * (Math.PI / 180);
    orbiter.x = origin.x + radius * Math.cos(rad);
    orbiter.y = origin.y + radius * Math.sin(rad);
    orbiter.rotation = (Math.atan2(orbiter.y-origin.y, orbiter.x-origin.x) * 180 / Math.PI);
    }
}
```

That still leaves you with one little math problem, which will be obvious when you run the code, but you can take care of that.

Comment: This code will only execute when a key is pressed, so you'd have to keep hitting the right button to change the angle which is not what you want.

Comment: YOU wrote: "... but I want it to do it only when the right arrow key is pressed. " That's exactly what my code does, no? You hold the key down and you orbit.

Comment: Note that I'm not the one who started this topic ;) But it is exactly my point that above code will not execute while you hold down the key but rather only once at the time you press it.

Comment: Not true. The KEY_DOWN event keeps firing - like a MOUSE_MOVE event. For example, if you make a simple test .fla with: stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, doit)  as the first line of code. Then add a 'function doit(e)' with a trace inside.

Comment: Damnit, you are totally right.. I assumed KEY_DOWN would work the same as the MOUSE_DOWN event, which does fire only once (and IMHO makes more sense). Upped your answer!

Comment: Did another test, with tracing an ENTER_FRAME event as well it seems the KEY_DOWN event polling isn't in sync with it. There also seems to be a small delay between the initial KEY_DOWN and the continuous polling after that. So the most fluid solution would still be using the ENTER_FRAME like Mattias suggested.